# Is there a way to download Google's voice recognition API so it can be used offline?

Tags: api, web-api, offline

I'm playing with Google's voice recognition for a personal project and I have a fun little Q&A program written in Python using it. The problem, as it were, is that it means I have to be connected to the internet to access the API or the program doesn't work.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can download the entire API so I can use it offline rather than being wifi dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to find out with Google themselves. My guest is that you cannnot, in the specific case of Google Voice recognition service. That's not because it is not technically feasible but because Google  simply hasn't designed it to be downloadabled and independant on the servers. As a counter-example, Apple's dictation services, that originally where dependant of an internet conection, now can be downloaded to be used off-line.